How to replace EARLIER function in DAX Calculated Column?
I recently read that you should not use the EARLIER function. I recently inherited a dataset file that uses this function and it keeps crashing, likely due to the EARLIER function. I am trying to convert this formula into the proper format using variables but I'm having some trouble.
The current code is set up like so to get the cumulative balance as of the most recent invoice. How can I adjust this to remove the EARLIER function but get the same result?
_Balance Cumulative =
calculate(sum(Invoices[Balance]),
          ALLEXCEPT(Invoices,Invoices[Customer ID + Company Desc]),
          filter(
             all(Invoices[Invoice Date]),Invoices[Invoice Date] <= 
                 EARLIER(Invoices[Invoice Date])))


Last week, I was tackling with this problem too. The solution is to create a new table. You can use "summarize" function. Let me share my DAX code and you can change your attributes.
//Attributes
//'Invoices table'[Line Job]=Invoice ID (use unique values without blank)
//'Invoices table'[Account]=Invoice Account (use account which has earliest invoice date)
//'Invoices table'[Total]=Invoice Amount (sum amount which has earliest invoice date)
//'Invoices table'[Invoice Date]=Invoice Date

Earliest Invoice Date = 
SUMMARIZE (
    FILTER('Invoices table', NOT(ISBLANK('Invoices table'[Line Job]))),
    'Invoices table'[Line Job]
    ,"Client" , CALCULATE(MIN('Invoices table'[Account]), 'Invoices table'[Invoice Date]= MIN('Invoices table'[Invoice Date]) )
    ,"Total Amount", CALCULATE(SUM('Invoices table'[Total]), 'Invoices table'[Invoice Date]= MIN('Invoices table'[Invoice Date]) ) 
    ,"Earliest Invoice Date", CALCULATE(
        MIN('Invoices table'[Invoice Date]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Invoices table', 'Invoices table'[Line Job])
    )
    
)

Hope it would be helpful 

EARLIER is not causing crashes. Try this:
_Balance Cumulative =
VAR x = MAX(Invoices[Invoice Date])

RETURN

calculate(sum(Invoices[Balance]),
          ALLEXCEPT(Invoices,Invoices[Customer ID + Company Desc]),
          filter(
             all(Invoices[Invoice Date]),Invoices[Invoice Date] <= 
                 x))

